# Identify records in data frame A not contained in data frame B

Tags: r, join, merge, match, dataframe

This is my first time posting here, so please be kind ;-)

**EDIT**
My question was closed before I had a chance to make the changes suggested to me. So I'm trying to do a better job now, thanks for everyone that answered so far!

### QUESTION

How can I identify records/rows in data frame `x.1` that are *not* contained in data frame `x.2` based on *all* attributes available (i.e. all columns) in the *most efficient* way?

### **EXAMPLE DATA**

```
> x.1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b=c(1,2,3,4,5))
> x.1
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5

> x.2 <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,3,4), b=c(1,1,99,3,4))
> x.2
  a  b
1 1  1
2 1  1
3 2 99
4 3  3
5 4  4
```

### DESIRED RESULT

```
  a b
2 2 2
5 5 5
```

### BEST SOLUTION SO FAR

by Prof. Brian Ripley and Gabor Grothendieck

```
> fun.12 <- function(x.1,x.2,...){
+     x.1p <- do.call("paste", x.1)
+     x.2p <- do.call("paste", x.2)
+     x.1[! x.1p %in% x.2p, ]
+ }
> fun.12(x.1,x.2)
  a b
2 2 2
5 5 5
> sol.12 <- microbenchmark(fun.12(x.1,x.2))
> sol.12 <- median(sol.12$time)/1000000000
> sol.12
> [1] 0.000207784
```

**A collection of all solutions tested so far is available at my [blog](http://rappster.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/identifying-records-in-data-frame-a-that-are-not-contained-in-fata-frame-b-a-comparison/)**

### FINAL EDIT 2011-10-14

Here's the best solution wrapped into a function 'mergeX()':

```
setGeneric(
    name="mergeX",
    signature=c("src.1", "src.2"),
    def=function(
        src.1,
        src.2,
        ...
    ){
    standardGeneric("mergeX")    
    }
)

setMethod(
    f="mergeX", 
    signature=signature(src.1="data.frame", src.2="data.frame"), 
    definition=function(
        src.1,
        src.2,
        do.inverse=FALSE,
        ...
    ){
    if(!do.inverse){
        out <- merge(x=src.1, y=src.2, ...)
    } else {
        if("by.y" %in% names(list(...))){
            src.2.0 <- src.2
            src.2 <- src.1
            src.1 <- src.2.0
        }
        src.1p <- do.call("paste", src.1)
        src.2p <- do.call("paste", src.2)
        out <- src.1[! src.1p %in% src.2p, ]
    }
    return(out)    
    }
)
```

Comment: This isn't a real question.  You post 8 different solutions to your own problem, the best of which (By Prof Brian Ripley) is only three lines of Base R code and is already packaged into a function.  What more do you want?

Comment: @Andrie, he probably wants my solution? :-))

Comment: @Tomas T: I actually was looking for something like this ;-)

Comment: @Andrie: I was afraid of something like this happening ;-) Still think I did pose a question and why can't questions be linked to a collection of possible solutions instead of solutions being scattered all over the place because everyone uses different wording to describe what he/she's after? Just wanted to help others a bit...

Comment: @songpants It would be better if you remove all of the solutions from your question and compose an answer to your own question that contains these solutions.  Also, a really good question should ideally contain sample data and expected results.  Then all answers can make use of this for benchmarking purposes.

Comment: @Andrie: okay, you've got a point there. I'm new to the interface and thinking about it, it really would have been better to provide the collected solutions as answers. Yet I do think I provided sample data (`x.1` and `x.2`) and clearly stated what the original problem was...

Comment: @songpants You can still modify your question and turn this into a good question.

Comment: @Andrie: yeah, tried it already but since I'm new, Stackoverflow tells me I have to wait 8 hours :-/ Thanks for the advice, though. Would you group the solutions into one answer, or make each one an individual answer so people can vote on it and stuff?

Comment: Pick the *one* you like best and answer it with that.  If you want to make a collection of cool answers, write a blog.

Comment: Also, remove solutions that don't solve the problem that you asked about (e.g. Solution 2).  They just clutter up an otherwise interesting comparison.

Comment: Okay, tried to improve my question. Maybe someone could reopen it as I'm really curious if there are yet better ways as I have to apply this to huge data frames, so efficiency really matters. Thanks!

Comment: My opinion is that closing this question was an really unconstructive and stupid move. Give him chance to improve this question. This way you force him to start a new one. Is that better?

Comment: @TomasT.: thanks for understanding ;-) Don't wanna make too big of a fuzz out of this, but do you think it's okay to flag this in order to have someone reviewing and maybe reopening it? By the way, I did follow the blog advice and you'll find all the solutions here: http://rappster.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/identifying-records-in-data-frame-a-that-are-not-contained-in-fata-frame-b-a-comparison/

Comment: @songpants, I think posting all solutions is perfectly OK, even in the question itself (they always say: "show what you have tried". If you don't show, they will close, if you show, they close also). But follow Josh's comment on removing solutions which are not solutions... I vote for reopen.

Comment: This question still needs for votes for reopening. I recommend to edit the question (add some solutions) and state clearly what your question is, and then flag it.

Comment: You don't need to repeat the answer you prefer in the question. The way stackoverflow is intended to be used is that you Accept the solution you prefer among those that were offered.  If you wish to further comment on that solution you can add a comment to it by clicking on the Add Comment button associated with that response.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: puh, a bit harder to do the right thing here than I thought, but I'll just keep trying again next time ;-) I do get the concept of stackoverflow (yet I also did make some mistakes), but it's hard to know when people think an approach posted is appropriate and when it's not as it's considered a "full-grown" answer already (as was/is obviously the case with my post). I'll just let it go at this point. Again, thanks everyone that responded! For those who care: updated the blog post at my blog (only valid solutions are benchmarked)

Comment: I don't really understand why this question was asked specifically aiming at maximum performance but then using as test data a data frame of tiny 2X5 dimension, where good solutions will differ by a few microseconds. It would make a lot more sense IMO to present a _large_ data set to test the different answers. Btw, you could add to your collection this method: `library(dplyr); anti_join(x.1, x.2)`. (I just realised that the question is 3 years old :-) )

Comment: `data.table` has an _anti-join_ as well: `x.1[!x.2, on = names(x.1)]` or for a complete working example: `library(data.table); setDT(x.1)[!setDT(x.2), on = names(x.1)]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are a few ways. #1 and #4 assume that the rows of `x.1` are unique. (If rows of `x.1` are not unique then they will return only one of the duplicates among the duplicated rows.) The others return all duplicates:

```
# 1
x.1[!duplicated(rbind(x.2, x.1))[-(1:nrow(x.2))],]

# 2
do.call("rbind", setdiff(split(x.1, rownames(x.1)), split(x.2, rownames(x.2))))

# 3
x.1p <- do.call("paste", x.1)
x.2p <- do.call("paste", x.2)
x.1[! x.1p %in% x.2p, ]

# 4
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from `x.1` except select * from `x.2`")
```

EDIT: x.1 and x.2 were swapped and this has been fixed.  Also have corrected note on limitations at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks Gabor! Not all of the approaches return the desired result ((2,2) and (5,5)) but gave me something to learn. Especially regarding 'sqldf'. Never looked at it before but seems to be really cool, thanks!

Comment: The roles of x.1 and x.2 were partly reversed in some of the solutions. I have edited it and they now should all give (2,2) and (5,5).

Comment: I updated my benchmark results and your third approach seems to be the fastest (0.0002066945 seconds)! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

What about using `merge` - the simplest possible solution - I'd think it's also the fastest.

```
tmp = merge(x.1, cbind(x.2, myid = 1:nrow(x.2)), all.x = TRUE)
    # provided that there's no column myid in both dataframes
tmp[is.na(tmp$myid), 1:ncol(x.1)] # the result
```

Corresponds to:

```
select x1.* 
from x1 natural left join x2 
where x2.myid is NULL
```

(you can also use sqldf to do that).

Note that the column `myid` is added to assure that there is some column w/o NA values. If you are sure there is already some column which doesn't contain NULL values, you can simplify the solution:

```
tmp = merge(x.1, x.2, all.x = TRUE)
    # provided that there's no column myid in both dataframes
tmp[is.na(tmp$some_column), 1:ncol(x.1)] # the result
```

Comment: Neat solution, but quite a claim about being the fastest - deserves an upvote if you can prove your claim is true.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tomas! That's the one I was looking for, but it's not the fastest ;-)

Comment: It ranks 7th compared to the ones I collected above (0.002583893 seconds using microbenchmark)

Comment: @Andrie, I'm too lazy to do that, I let the test to songpants... You might however be right, it's not so obvious: in SQL it would be the fastest because it is optimized for joins, with R's merge I'm not so sure now...

Comment: @songpants, we cross-talked :-) thanks for measurements, and yeah, my worries about R's merge came true... Thanks.

Comment: @songpants, note that if you are sure there is some column without NA values you can simplify the solution, see my edit.

Comment: @TomasT.: thanks, I'll have another look at your answer. Thanks for taking the time!