# In large dataset, deleted selected dataset based on another small daseset

Tags: r

I have an large dataset(d1) like this.

```
         SNP CHR       POS A1 A2     OR      P
       rs10   7  92221824  A  C 1.1008 0.2371
 rs1000000  12 125456933  G  A 0.9864 0.6714
 rs10000010   4  21227772  C  T 0.9710 0.2693
 rs10000012   4   1347325  G  C 1.0045 0.9087
 rs10000013   4  36901464  C  A 1.0198 0.5379
 rs10000017   4  84997149  T  C 0.9576 0.1912
```

I have a small dataset (d2)like this:

```
         SNP CHR       POS A1 A2     OR      P
 rs1000000  12 125456933  G  A 0.9864 0.6714
 rs10000017   4  84997149  T  C 0.9576 0.1912
```

Now, i want to delete all the date set information in d1 which has the information of d2. The result should be like this:

```
         SNP CHR       POS A1 A2     OR      P
      rs10   7  92221824  A  C 1.1008 0.2371
 rs10000010   4  21227772  C  T 0.9710 0.2693
 rs10000012   4   1347325  G  C 1.0045 0.9087
 rs10000013   4  36901464  C  A 1.0198 0.5379
```

I try to search on this web to see similar method to deal with this, but could not find the answer. Hope some one can help me for this. Many thanks.

Comment: Is a match in the `SNP` column sufficient, or does the entire row need to be checked?

Comment: Some discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728462/identify-records-in-data-frame-a-not-contained-in-data-frame-b

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `SNP` is a unique key.

```
d1 <- read.table(text="SNP CHR       POS A1 A2     OR      P
rs10   7  92221824  A  C 1.1008 0.2371
rs1000000  12 125456933  G  A 0.9864 0.6714
rs10000010   4  21227772  C  T 0.9710 0.2693
rs10000012   4   1347325  G  C 1.0045 0.9087
rs10000013   4  36901464  C  A 1.0198 0.5379
rs10000017   4  84997149  T  C 0.9576 0.1912", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

d2 <- read.table(text="         SNP CHR       POS A1 A2     OR      P
 rs1000000  12 125456933  G  A 0.9864 0.6714
 rs10000017   4  84997149  T  C 0.9576 0.1912", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


library(data.table)

d1 <- data.table(d1, key="SNP")
d2 <- data.table(d2, key="SNP")

d1[!J(d2)]

#          SNP CHR      POS A1 A2     OR      P
#1:       rs10   7 92221824  A  C 1.1008 0.2371
#2: rs10000010   4 21227772  C  T 0.9710 0.2693
#3: rs10000012   4  1347325  G  C 1.0045 0.9087
#4: rs10000013   4 36901464  C  A 1.0198 0.5379
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `rbind` the data.frames and then find the duplicates:

```
dx <- rbind(d1,d2)
dx[!(duplicated(dx)|rev(duplicated(dx[nrow(dx):1,]))),]
         SNP CHR      POS A1 A2     OR      P
1       rs10   7 92221824  A  C 1.1008 0.2371
3 rs10000010   4 21227772  C  T 0.9710 0.2693
4 rs10000012   4  1347325  G  C 1.0045 0.9087
5 rs10000013   4 36901464  C  A 1.0198 0.5379
```

Note that you have to scan forwards and backwards to detect all non-unique elements.

Comment: This may remove more duplicates than requested in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

To remove only rows in d1 that match exactly with some row from d2, without using data.table and without assuming any column is a key, you'll have to compare every row against every other row, such as this:

```
d1[sapply(seq(nrow(d1)), function(i) all(sapply(seq(nrow(d2)), function(j) any(d1[i,]!=d2[j,])))),]
```

So I recommend setting up a key first, especially if d1 (or d2) is large, and follow Roland's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
mydata<-mtcars
mydata1<-mydata[1:10,1:4]
mydata2<-mydata[4:15,1:4]
mydata1[!(mydata1$mpg %in% mydata2$mpg & mydata1$cyl %in% mydata2$cyl & mydata1$disp %in% mydata2$disp & mydata1$hp %in% mydata2$hp) ,]
               mpg cyl disp  hp
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93
```

Comment: This may remove non-duplicated rows... Consider this example: `d1 <- data.frame(a=2:1, b=1:2); d2 <- data.frame(a=1:2, b=1:2); d1[!(d1$a %in% d2$a & d1$b %in% d2$b),]`.