# Differences between two data frames in R

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames, each with 9 columns, and DF2 is a subset of DF1. I'm trying to create a third data frame that contains only the contents of DF1 that are NOT present in DF2.

What is the most efficient way of doing this? I can write a while loop, but I was wondering if there is another way (besides `sqldf` as for some reason I cannot upload it into my R Studio) that I can do this?

Comment: do you have to look for duplicates using all columns? or are there any unique row identifier or a combination few variables that can work as identifier?

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example and also add the expected result, otherwise answers will not be very accurate!

Answer (score 1):

The following can work (directly from [Identify records in data frame A not contained in data frame B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728462/identify-records-in-data-frame-a-not-contained-in-data-frame-b))

```
fun.12 <- function(x.1,x.2,...){
     x.1p <- do.call("paste", x.1)
     x.2p <- do.call("paste", x.2)
     x.1[! x.1p %in% x.2p, ]
}

DF1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b=c(1,2,3,4,5))
DF2 <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,3,4), b=c(1,1,99,3,4))
fun.12(DF1, DF2)

#   a b
# 2 2 2
# 5 5 5
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have been more clear, DF2 is a partial subset of DF1. DF23 was made using a merge of DF1 and another DF. Long story short, I am trying to find out which rows two data frames share, and which rows differ. I made DF2 by merginging DF1 with another DF. DF2 is what they share. Now I am trying to find out what rows are different.

Comment: OK, please clarify in the original post. The code I posted returns all the rows that are either in DF1 but not in DF2 or in DF2 but not in DF1. If DF2 is not actually a subset of DF1, then this code doesn't do what you wanted.

Comment: OK, I updated my response. It looks like this is actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728462/identify-records-in-data-frame-a-not-contained-in-data-frame-b