# How do I tag rows with two variables that match rows in a second data frame? R

Tags: r

I have a two large datasets df1 and df2. df2 is a subset of df1. I want to tag df1 rows that are present in df2 with "Yes" and others with "No". Rows do not contain any unique variable values. I would like to match values of multiple variables. However, I get incorrect results using the %in% operator. I also tried a nested for loop that looped over each row of df1 and compared it with each row of df2. It produces the correct results but with the size of my datasets, it would takes days to complete.

Please see the following example:

```
df1 <- data.frame( Col1 = c( "d1", "d2", "d3", "d1"), 
               Col2 = c( "n1", "n2", "n1", "n2" ))
df2 <- data.frame( Col1 = c( "d1", "d2" ), Col2 = c( "n1", "n2" ))
df1$Res <- "No"
df1.len <- nrow( df1 )

for ( i in 1:df1.len ){
  if ( df1$Col1[i] %in% df2$Col1 & 
     df1$Col2[i] %in% df2$Col2 ){
  df1$Res[i] <- "Yes"
  }
}
df1
df2
```

Output:

> df1
>         Col1 Col2 Res
>       1   d1   n1 Yes
>       2   d2   n2 Yes
>       3   d3   n1  No
>       4   d1   n2 Yes
>
> df2
>     Col1 Col2
>   1   d1   n1
>   2   d2   n2

As you can see, row 4 of df1 is not present in df2, but is still tagged as Yes. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I have spent last couple of days looking at SO and other forums without luck. Thanks.

Comment: Should be easy to adapt something from [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728462/identify-records-in-data-frame-a-not-contained-in-data-frame-b): "Identify records in data frame A not contained in data frame B"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is very similar to Ananda's, just a little bit less snazzy, but it might make a bit more sense if you're new to R, which judging by your question I'm guessing you are.

```
df1 <- data.frame( Col1 = c( "d1", "d2", "d3", "d1"), 
               Col2 = c( "n1", "n2", "n1", "n2" ))
df2 <- data.frame( Col1 = c( "d1", "d2" ), Col2 = c( "n1", "n2" ))

df1$col3 <- paste0(df1$Col1,df1$Col2) # create a composite of the row
df2$col3 <- paste0(df2$Col1,df2$Col2) # repeat

df1$col3 %in% df2$col3
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

You don't need to append the col3s to the data frames you're using, it's just the way I did it.

Comment: thank you for your solution. It worked fantastically. You are right on both fronts: I am new to R and your answer made a lot of sense. I did not append the pasted variable to dfs. Then I used ifelse() function to add Yes/No to df1 using the logical output from %in% conditional. I will upload the code I generated shortly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
duplicated(rbind(df2, df1))[-sequence(nrow(df2))]  ## Might not be reliable...
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

or one of these:

```
interaction(df1) %in% interaction(df2)
do.call(paste, df1) %in% do.call(paste, df2)
```

You can easily change `TRUE` to "Yes" and `FALSE` to "No" if you want, but keeping the logical values might be more useful.

Comment: (Now I see that Henrik's duplicate has virtually exactly these options.)

Comment: Your first answer would give a wrong result if df1 has rows that are duplicates, but not in df2, correct?

Comment: @MatthewPlourde, Yes, I suppose so. Good call.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer using dplyr, which is much faster than base R. First you create a unique ID for each row, then create a new variable based on a logical vector comparing the IDs.

```
require(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame( Col1 = c( "d1", "d2", "d3", "d1"), 
               Col2 = c( "n1", "n2", "n1", "n2" ))
df2 <- data.frame( Col1 = c( "d1", "d2" ), Col2 = c( "n1", "n2" ))

df2 <- mutate(df2, Col3 = paste0(Col1, Col2))
df1 <- mutate(df1, 
  Col3 = paste0(Col1, Col2),
  Res = ifelse(Col3 %in% df2$Col3, "Yes", "No")
  )
```

Using `duplicated()` (as in Ananda's answer) is syntactically simple, but it may be very slow depending on how many columns your data frames have.

Answer (score 1):

This provides the correct answers, but will need to be tweaked if your columns in df1 and df2 have different names:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Col1 = c("d1", "d2", "d3", "d1"), 
                  Col2 = c("n1", "n2", "n1", "n2"))
df1.len <- nrow(df1)
df1 <- cbind(df1, unique=seq(1:df1.len))

df2 <- data.frame(Col1 = c("d1","d2"), Col2 = c("n1","n2"))
df1$Res <- "No"

match <- merge(df1,df2,by=c("Col1","Col2"))

for (i in 1:df1.len){
if (df1$unique[i] %in% match$unique) {
    df1$Res[i] <- "Yes"
  }
}
```

Comment: Don, thank you for your response. My df1 is almost 1 million rows and the combination of a for loop with if conditional takes a very long time. However, I combined the idea of creating a unique value with ifelse (which is a vectorized function and does not need a for loop) to get the desired results. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `split`, e.g.,

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=letters[1:10])
df2 <- df1[1:5,]
df1$in.df2 <- split(df1, rownames(df1)) %in% split(df2, rownames(df2))
#     a b in.df2
# 1   1 a   TRUE
# 2   2 b   TRUE
# 3   3 c   TRUE
# 4   4 d   TRUE
# 5   5 e   TRUE
# 6   6 f  FALSE
# 7   7 g  FALSE
# 8   8 h  FALSE
# 9   9 i  FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unless I am missing something, this won't work because there are no rownames in df1 and df2. I want to test df1 rows for both variables in df2.

Comment: There have to be row names. Alternatively, you could replace `rownames(df)` with `seq(nrow(df))`