# Get indices of common rows from two different dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr

I  have two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(cola = c("dum1", "dum2", "dum3"), colb = c("bum1", "bum2", "bum3"), colc = c("cum1", "cum2", "cum3"))
```

and:

```
df2 <- data.frame(cola = c("dum1", "dum2", "dum4"), colb = c("bum1", "bum2", "bum3"))
```

I need to find the indices of the rows in dataframe `df1` in which the columns `cola` and `colb` are the same, here it would be row 1 and row 2. I know the `inner_join` function from the `dplyr` package but this results in a new dataframe. I just need a vector with the indices. I could do this with `which` for each column needed but this would be ugly if I need to find common rows based on a large number of columns.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Related: [How do I tag rows with two variables that match rows in a second data frame? R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809225/how-do-i-tag-rows-with-two-variables-that-match-rows-in-a-second-data-frame-r), where output is logical instead of index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The more general typical way of solving this would look like:

```
colsToUse <- intersect(colnames(df1), colnames(df2))
match(do.call("paste", df1[, colsToUse]), do.call("paste", df2[, colsToUse]))
```

[1]  1  2 NA

Comment: I decided in the end to go with `which(do.call(paste, s.opts1[, c(2:3)]) == do.call(paste, dm.rw1))`but the `do.call`did the trick. So thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
 which(apply(df1[1:2]==df2,1,prod)==1)
```

Comment: Thank you, but this gives an error that levels of factors are not the same: `Error in Ops.factor(left, right)`

Comment: Ensure your dataframe elements are characters instead of factors. ie `df1=data.frame(...,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Comment: This helps, but I do not want to have to convert it to characters before and find the `do.call` solution from RolandASc more direct. Thank you nevertheless.